# ByRef arugement type mismatch VBA Discussion

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I am writing a method in VBA and I received a ByRef argument type mismatch. After doing some research I found a quick fix--store my value in another variable and then pass that new variable into my method. Can anyone explain to me the method behind the madness? What is going on under the hood in VBA? Why will it not accept my original variable?

Context:

```
For Each excl In excelFiles
    Dim temp As String
    temp = excl
    Call uploadExcelFile(temp, schema)
Next excl
```

Method used:

```
Private Sub uploadExcelFile(excelWb As String, schema As Worksheet)
```

excelFiles is an Array of Strings. Please let me know if you guys would like anymore info. Excited to learn what is going on here.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you're looping through a string array, the VBA for-each loop expects a variant as the loop "counter" (`excl` in your case).

You can use

`Call uploadExcelFile(Cstr(excl), schema)`

to avoid that intermediate `temp` variable.

Comment: Thanks Tim! So this means that excl is no longer a String but it is some weird intermediate type that is used by the for each loop?

Comment: You cannot use string in For Each loop, it either has to be a Variant, or an Object. Since excl cannot be declared as a string, you need to explicitly convert that variant in a string so that your method can understand and accept it as string.